# Solve for x and y, $x^3+7x^2+35x+27=y^3$ where x and y are integers.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Okay, I have done parity check. I have taken cases of $x$ being odd or even and been working with mod 7 but nothing happened. How to proceed with further? Please help!
This is my try In case 1, where $x$ is odd and $y$ is even $x^3+7x^2+35x+27≡0,5,6\bmod 7$ so $y^3≡6\bmod 7$ In case 2, where $x$ is even and $y$ is odd similarly we can show $y^3≡6\bmod 7$. Apologies, if I am doing anything wrong since I am a beginner.

Comment: Do we have to understand that $x$ and $y$ are integers ??

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes

Comment: Can you share your solution @Moo

Comment: What "nothing" happened when you did parity check and $\textrm{mod}\ 7$?

Comment: @Unknown: Can you share **yours**, till whatever step it is?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 This is my try
In case 1, where x is odd and y is even $x^3+7x^2+35x+27\equiv 0,5,6 (mod 7)$ so $y^3\equiv 6(mod 7)$
In case 2, where x is even and y is odd similarly we can show $y^3\equiv 6(mod 7)$.
Apologies, if I am doing anything wrong since I am a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I highly suggest you put this in your post itself. There is an "edit" button just below the post.

Comment: $y^3\cong 0\pmod 7$ is also possible

Comment: For $\quad -100\le x,y\le100\quad$ a spreadsheet reveals only two solutions

$$x^3+7x^2+35x+27-y^3=0 
\implies (x,y)\in
\big\{(0,3),\space (4,7)\big\}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(x+2)^3<x^3+7x^2+35x+27<(x+3)^3$ outside some interval $[a,b]$. Determine possible values for $a,b$, prove that there cannot be any solutions $(x,y)$ where $x$ is outside this interval and check the finitely many cases in $[a,b]$.